# Magento 1.9.0.2 migration to 2.0.7 clean install error: "composer.json" cannot be found

Tags: magento2, migration, composer, magento-2.0.7

When I issue this command on bash shell (*Copied directly from this [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html#data-migrate-prereq)*):

```
composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
```

I get the following error

> "*File "composer.json" cannot be found in the current directory*"

I've included the path of `composer.json` in the `$PATH` but still get the above error

I am migrating from Magento 1.9.0.2 to a clean install of Magento 2.0.7 from a bitnami AWS AMI Ubuntu 14.x server. Running the command on Mac OS X. I've updated composer.

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the command from the root of your Magento install to make sure that your `$PATH` isn't the issue. If that still doesn't work, I would check to make sure that the ownership and permissions on the `composer.json` are correct. It could be that its there and you are hitting it, but your user doesn't have rights to the file.